# How do I create a Drupal View to display last activity date.

Tags: activities, drupal-views

I'm trying to set up a View of Clients, Case Managers and date of last activity.  Most of the clients have many activities, but I only want the most recent one displayed.

Normally, I would use the Multiple Field Settings in Drupal Views, but it isn't an option for the CiviCRM Activity Date or Activity ID fields.

Everything else is working but can't get it to only display the last date.

Any ideas?

Asked this question before here: 
[http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35580](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35580/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All right...I did it but just wanted to follow up.

Expand Advances in the View UI, click next to Aggregation on the word No.
[image]

Turn it on.

Now Add the Scheduled Activity Date field.

[image]

Click Apply, then the Aggregation options will pop up.

Select Maximum in the drop down list.

[image]

Then click Apply.

Here is part of my output (with other fields too of course).

[image]

Comment: nice share pmoz.